# Thread shouldn't be running anymore

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object and a script attached to it.
I want to send data to a web server in script's `Update` function.

So I create a WWW object.
But after some time Unity begins to report "thread shouldn't be running anymore".

Here is the Update function:

```
void Update () 
    {
        //ambil tindakan dari server

        //bikin object www
        //bikin request ke localhost/vacuum?r=index/action
        //ambil hasilnya (json)

        //ambil perintah

        //eksekusi perintah

        //scan lingkungan
        var fwd = transform.TransformDirection (Vector3.forward);
        var left = transform.TransformDirection (Vector3.left);
        var right = transform.TransformDirection (Vector3.right);
        var back = transform.TransformDirection (Vector3.back);
        RaycastHit hit_fwd = new RaycastHit(), 
                   hit_left = new RaycastHit(), 
                   hit_right = new RaycastHit(), 
                   hit_back = new RaycastHit();
        bool bool_hit_fwd, bool_hit_left, bool_hit_right, bool_hit_back;
        float 
            distance_fwd = 0.0f, 
            distance_left = 0.0f, 
            distance_right = 0.0f, 
            distance_back = 0.0f;

        bool_hit_fwd = Physics.Raycast (transform.position, fwd, out hit_fwd, 50);
        bool_hit_left = Physics.Raycast (transform.position, left, out hit_left, 50);
        bool_hit_right = Physics.Raycast (transform.position, right, out hit_right, 50);
        bool_hit_back = Physics.Raycast (transform.position, back, out hit_back, 50);

        if (bool_hit_fwd) 
        {
            distance_fwd = hit_fwd.distance;
        }

        if (bool_hit_left) 
        {
            distance_left = hit_left.distance;
        }

        if (bool_hit_right) 
        {
            distance_right = hit_right.distance;
        }

        if (bool_hit_back) 
        {
            distance_back = hit_back.distance;
        }

        transform.Rotate(0, 0.01f, 0);

        print(
            "rot-y/pos-x/pos-y :: fwd/left/right/back = " + 
            transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y + '/' +
            transform.position.x + '/' +
            transform.position.y + '/' +

            " :: " +
            distance_fwd + '/' + 
            distance_left + '/' + 
            distance_right + '/' + 
            distance_back);

        String url = "http://localhost:1234/minibrain?" +
            "roty=" + transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y.ToString() + 
            "&posx=" + transform.position.x.ToString() + 
            "&posy=" + transform.position.y.ToString() + 
            "&fwddist=" + distance_fwd.ToString() + 
            "&leftdist=" + distance_left.ToString() + 
            "&rightdist=" + distance_right.ToString() + 
            "&backdist=" + distance_back.ToString();

        WWW www = new WWW(url);
    }
```

There is no error. Data was received correctly by the web server. But the data transmission rate decreased greatly. Like down to 10 transmissions per second from 100 transmissions per second.

Is there a way to create WWW object without causing "thread shouldn't be running anymore"?

Comment: Do note that the [unity] tag is not for Unity 3D. So please just stick to using the [unity3d] tag.

Comment: Yes Bart. I think you have reminded me about that. A long time ago. Thanks.

Comment: Hah, okay, I don't recall. You're certainly not the only one making that tiny mistake. I hope my answer is useful to you though. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is most likely that you run everything in your `Update()`. That will generally steam ahead as fast as it can. Your call to WWW will return immediately (it won't wait until all actions are done) and you move on to your next frame.

As a result, if your Update runs fast enough, you'll end up with more and more WWW objects that haven't completed. I don't know how fast it is currently running, but you have to ask yourself if you either need that many data points, or if going trough a WWW call is the best approach. If available on your setup, a socket connection might work better.

If you're happy with sending data as fast as it can be handled, make sure you check for the [`isDone`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW-isDone.html) by making the call a coroutine, or in that case just yield for its return. (Don't use a while loop on it) Or perhaps just determine a regular interval at which you'd like the data, and send it at that, if that ends up being easier on your setup there.

Answer (score 1):

Use [coroutines](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Coroutines.html). It is bad experience to implement web requests in Update() function, because web requests need some time to be executed.